# Is there is any way to display large quantity of assets image as listview?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have about 300+ images as assets images in my app. I want to display all of them with their short description in my app. Is there is any way to display them as listview instead of giving their path individually? I want that there is a way like this so that I can access each with their index.

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: litems.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
     return Text(litems[index]);
    }
)
```

Also if not...Please suggest me the best way to show such large quantities of assets images.

Comment: Your code will work for this case

Comment: how can I access images with index  like images[index], should I create separate data file for images path?

Comment: create image path list from  assets images

Comment: so should I manually type each image path. I think its so cumbersome to type 300+ images path in a list? Any other option...

Comment: is below solution works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Declare List variable**

```
List<String> imagesList;
```

**Fetch Images:**

```
 Future _initImages() async {
    final manifestContent =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('AssetManifest.json');

    final Map<String, dynamic> manifestMap = json.decode(manifestContent);


    final imagePaths = manifestMap.keys
        .where((String key) => key.contains('images/')) // mention folder where all images exists
        .toList();

    setState(() {
      imagesList = imagePaths;
    });
  }
```

**Call from initState()**

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _initImages();
  }
```

Finally, you can use `imagesList` in your `ListView`

Comment: what is 'AssetsManifest.json' file means here. Sorry I didn't get it ..

Comment: it is used to fetch data from your JSON. Accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: thanks it works  but I didn't see AssetManifest.json file.  Is it not accessible to us.

Comment: @jitsm655 my images name contains whitespace and while print I imagePaths,  I get something like this ' my%20image%20.jpg '  and when I give this path to Image it gives unable to load assets error. Any solution?